# Versioning API Helpers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

We have a versioned API that follows all the conventions of Rails API versioning. i.e

```
module API::V4
  class Test < ApiController
  end
end
```

But is there a proper way to version helpers? The current helpers directory looks like something like this:

```
app
|__helpers
   |__helper_a.rb
   |__helper_b.rb
```

and all helpers are defined modules.

Is there a way to do this?

```
module Helpers::V2
  class HelperA
  end
end
```

I tried creating a directory `app/helpers/v2/helper_a.rb`, adding `app/helpers/helpers.rb` and defining `module Helpers` But for some reason rails always fails to see `Helpers::V2::HelperA`

Comment: Versioning an API makes sense, it's a public interface and old versions must continue to be supported. Why do you want to version the helpers?

Comment: @Schwern Because I want the older APIs to use the old helpers, and create new ones for the newer versions. Is there a more simplified way of making it maybe?

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails searches each subdirectory of `app` starting from the subdirectory. `app/models/foo/bar.rb` contains `Foo::Bar` not `Models::Foo::Bar`. `app/controllers/api/v4/test.rb` contains `Api::V4::Test`, not `Controllers::Api::V4::Test`.

So `app/helpers/v2/helper_a.rb` contains `V2::HelperA`.

```
module V2
  module HelperA
  end
end
```

If you want to relate the helper version with your API version, it makes sense to mirror the directory structure.

```
# app/helpers/api/v2/helper_a.rb

# A helper for API v2.
module Api
  module V2
    module HelperA
    end
  end
end
```

Note that it's `Api` to follow Rails conventions. The autoloader will map `app/helpers/api/v2/helper_a.rb` to `Api::V2::HelperA`. It *might* work with the Rails 5 autoloader, but not the Rails 6 autoloader.

If we use `API::V2::HelperA`...

```
[1] pry(main)> API::V2::HelperA
NameError: uninitialized constant API
Did you mean?  Api
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Just a little correction though: Rails expects all helpers to be modules and not classes, and thus any tests will fail if you define it as a class.